# How to change manually project.pbxproj file in Xcode during React-native upgrade?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, upgrade, pbxproj

I need to upgrade my React-native app from 0.61.0 to 0.62.0. The best safety way to do it manually with React Native Upgrade Helper https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper. But during this way a lot of changes need to do in ios/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file in Xcode. But I'm not so familiar with it.  Can somebody recommend me please how to make changes in project.pbxproj in Xcode for upgrade of RN version?

Comment: Hi bro , did u find any easy way ? I am also not familar with ios part. There are alot of changes in this file.

Comment: No, I have not found yet

Comment: So how did u do that? U havent upgraded then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `ios/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` you can manually change the version by editing all the `MARKETING_VERSION` variables values, make sure to change the version on `package.json` as well.

Once you did, just clean the current cache on XCode (command + K) and generate a new `.ipa` as you're used to do. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

On your main project folder go to the `ios/` folder. Right-click on your `MyApp.xcodeproj` file and select "**Show Package Contents**" in the context menu.
Once inside you will find the `project.pbxproj` file, open it with Xcode (just double-click). I assume you already have it installed.
There you gonna be able to make the changes that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The xcodeproj is really a folder. Make a duplicate and change the .xcodeproj extension to .txt or remove the dot. Then you'll be able to see the files inside the folder. Do whatever you need to do then put the dot back or rename the extension.